# Application tried to present modally an active controller - crashing, why?

Tags: ios, segue

Interesting that I don't present modally, but using segue:

This how I trigger segue:

```
_centerAndRightContainerViewController!.performSegueWithIdentifier("xxx", sender: self)
```

Segue is set up in Interface Builder:

[image]

And here is the container class implementation, but I don't think any wrong is with it, in iOS7 in old Xcode 5 I used several of segues:

```
var _centerAndRightContainerViewController: CenterAndRightContainerViewController? = nil
var _selectedCenterAndRightContainerViewController: UIViewController? = nil

class CenterAndRightContainerViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        _centerAndRightContainerViewController = self
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject?) {

        let fromViewController = segue.sourceViewController as UIViewController
        let toViewController = segue.destinationViewController as UIViewController

        if(!_selectedCenterAndRightContainerViewController) {

            addChildViewController(toViewController)

            view.addSubview(toViewController.view)
            toViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
            toViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds

        } else {

            let selectedCenterChildViewController = _selectedCenterAndRightContainerViewController as UIViewController
            Utility.swap(selectedCenterChildViewController, toViewController: toViewController, containerViewController: self)
        }

        _selectedCenterAndRightContainerViewController = toViewController
    }
}
```

And here is the full crash report:

```
2014-08-02 12:57:30.349 PFB[66014:2653163] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller <_TtC3PFB14ViewController: 0x7af35af0>.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0104d646 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x009208bf objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   UIKit                               0x0155e41e presentationControllerClassForPresentationStyle + 0
    3   UIKit                               0x01560881 -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 333
    4   UIKit                               0x01564e1b -[UIViewController _showViewController:withAction:sender:] + 213
    5   UIKit                               0x017988b1 -[UIStoryboardShowSegue perform] + 143
    6   UIKit                               0x01a07d43 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 217
    7   UIKit                               0x015532f0 -[UIViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:] + 72
    8   PFB                                 0x0004570d _TFC3PFB23LeftTableViewController9tableViewfS0_FTGSQCSo11UITableView_23didSelectRowAtIndexPathGSQCSo11NSIndexPath__T_ + 5309
    9   PFB                                 0x000457f5 _TToFC3PFB23LeftTableViewController9tableViewfS0_FTGSQCSo11UITableView_23didSelectRowAtIndexPathGSQCSo11NSIndexPath__T_ + 101
    10  UIKit                               0x0150b091 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1559
    11  UIKit                               0x0150b23c -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 285
    12  UIKit                               0x0151042d __38-[UITableView touchesEnded:withEvent:]_block_invoke + 43
    13  UIKit                               0x01425a9e ___afterCACommitHandler_block_invoke + 15
    14  UIKit                               0x01425a49 _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 415
    15  UIKit                               0x0142585e _afterCACommitHandler + 545
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00f70c6e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00f70bb0 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 400
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00f65f7a __CFRunLoopRun + 1226
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00f657eb CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00f6561b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x03fc729c GSEventRunModal + 192
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x03fc70d9 GSEventRun + 104
    23  UIKit                               0x013fc3d6 UIApplicationMain + 1526
    24  PFB                                 0x0004f6e1 top_level_code + 97
    25  PFB                                 0x0004f71b main + 43
    26  libdyld.dylib                       0x028c0ac9 start + 1
```

Comment: Please provide a fully symbolicated crash report and show where in your code the app crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution for my own problem is quiet strange

**1)** I have subclassed UIStoryboardSegue, added to project, like this

```
import UIKit

class EmptySegue: UIStoryboardSegue {


    override func perform() {

    }
}
```

**2)** And set to the Segue Class field in Story Board a string called: "`_TtC3PFB10EmptySegue`", and transition is working now.

[image]

Don't ask me where I found the magic string, why it is working, it is a mistery. Maybe just a bad side effect of iOS8.